# Find the row index when dropdownlist value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have an HTML Table with dropdownlist on every row. I want everytime I change the value of the dropdownlist, the background of that row be changed to indicate that there is something changed on the dropdownlist.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>
            <Select onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value='2">2</option></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(a) {
        var cells = document.getElementById("table1").rows[a].cells;
        for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's still not working, how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: can you use jquery or is just a plain javascript answer needed?

Comment: whichever works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery then change your function to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(a)
    {
       $(a).parent().parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
    </script>
```

If you were going to just use plain javascript then it would be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(a)
        {
           a.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: say that I have made some changes on the dropdownlist so some rows' background color has changed. How do I return all them back into the default color by button click event?

Comment: You can use the same function and just have an additional parameter for color to set it to.

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the default background color hexcode?

Comment: if it has a color before hand using a style then you can get the color the same way these functions set it.

Comment: Then the background color must be #ffffff

Comment: it's returning a white color. I am using the ASP.net MVC 4 so the default background color is kinda greyish. Do you know the hexcode?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='yellow';"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
function myFunction(a)
{
    a.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Then make sure you fix a little typo you have on the select (single quote instead of double quotes):

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td><select onchange="myFunction(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/GkvA9/